# Editing out the Ruby tag from a Ruby-on-Rails question

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

[Someone suggested an edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52706) to remove the [ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby) tag with the reason:

> ruby != RoR

I was tempted to reject the edit, since [ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby) is a valid tag in my opinion for [ruby-on-rails](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails). The user is a good contributor in the [ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby) tag on SO so I was doubtful what would be the best option here.

Do we reject edit like that or are we separating Ruby and RoR?

Here is a [rejected](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48210) similar edit and here is an [accepted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/51940) one.

Comment: Sounds like the same type of person that would remove the JavaScript tag from a jQuery question.

Comment: With all due respect to the users who accepted the last mentioned edit, I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Editing out [ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby) from [ruby-on-rails](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) is basically equivalent to editing out [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) or [vb.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) from [asp.net](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) questions (containing code in the relevant language).

In short… it's a stupid idea.

Please reject such edits as vandalism / non-improvement.

A question concerning RoR code can be reviewed by [ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby) people, whether they know RoR or not. It's just that RoR people may have better insight into the framework. In the end it's still Ruby code and should be tagged accordingly.

Comment: That what my first impression was but I wanted confirmation that what we wanted here.

Answer (score 16):

In short, our rule is that every question must have a language tag. There may be other tags which are redundant or more specific (e.g. [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) or [ruby-on-rails](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)), but the language tag is still required.

Comment: Is [tag:ruby-on-rails] considered a framework tag and not a language tag then? If so perhaps it's worth adding that Ruby should also be tagged in the ruby-on-rails tag excerpt.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I agree, taking a look at the tags it's pretty clear one is a language and one is a framework,  but it would be a good idea to put that in the excerpt for ROR.

Comment: Please, see my answer below and comment smth there or in the chatroom http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor

Answer (score 15):

This is one area where the community stance is fairly unanimous. **The language tag is the most important**. In fact, all questions on Code Review have the language tag.

In fairness, the thought behind the perpetrator is likely that it is a more specific subcategory and implies the derived tag. Perhaps they desired an additional tag but five tags is more than sufficient.

Once you consider the actual way tags are used the mistake becomes obvious.
Say there are people who are interested in Ruby in general, and follow the tag. If we allowed this, these would be helpful people are then no longer able to color-distinguish, search or filter and find the post.

Answer (score -2):

The problem about Ruby/Rails tags is that 90% of these questions are really so much about Rails that:

1. If you throw out the part of code that is Rails-related, there would be nothing left to review
2. The guy who is interested in Ruby language related questions has nothing to say

I've [asked the same question on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65238/150545) already six years ago and it was decided to omit the Ruby tag, so I assumed it should be the same logic here. If you follow the links there you'll see another answers accepted in the same way:

- [about language tags in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61365/150545)
- [about JS/Jquery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32450/150545) even while I suppose it does not have the *90% problem* that I mentioned higher

Comment: As long as Rails is still written in the Ruby language, it should carry the Ruby tag. Do you contest this?

Comment: @Mast, yes I do. Just repeating the obvious relation of one tag to another one isn't an argument.

Comment: That goes against the nature of how Code Review works. We will not make an exception for Ruby.

Comment: The page you are commenting on right now is exactly to clarify what it "the nature". Saying "it's wrong because it's wrong" is wrong.

Comment: [*And don't omit applicable tags to shield readers from subjects they're not interested in: you can easily craft a search to exclude tags you aren't personally interested in.*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61365/213556) - I find that this goes against your idea of removing the Ruby tag from RoR questions.

Comment: [Here is one question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/132615/9357) that contains some Ruby code as background information, but the code that is intended for review is actually an ERb template, which only marginally qualifies as "Ruby". I'm OK with leaving out the [tag:ruby] tag for that exceptional case. Most Rails questions are written in Ruby, though, and our convention is to have a language tag on every question; [tag:ruby-on-rails] is merely the name of the framework. I'd rather not drop the [tag:python] tag from [tag:django] questions, etc.